# How do I cancel the event in a setTimeout() after clearing the timeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a live console for a Discord so that I can see errors while I'm away from my computer. I'm trying to make it so that every time the listener will receive data it will clear the previous timeout and make a new one so that the same thing is not sent `x` amount of times because the listener was called `x` amount of times. Now I'm at my problem. I can clear the timeout but not the event inside of it.

```
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    stdout = stdout + data.toString();

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send([stdout], {
            code: true,
            split: true
        });
    })
});
```

So this code ends up still sending `x` amount of times. How would I cancel the event inside to fix this?

Edit: Dumb mistake by me. I accidentally deleted the timeout while cleaning up my code. The code bellow solves everything.

```
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    stdout = stdout + data.toString();

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send([stdout], {
            code: true,
            split: true
        });
    }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: You don't set a time value on your timeout? Don't you want 100 milliseconds or something? Otherwise, it's basically immediately calling the lambda

Comment: Oh I must have deleted the time by accident while cleaning up my code. It used to be 3000 ms.

Comment: "The code bellow [sic] solves everything." So... there's no more problem?

Comment: Yeah it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake by me. I accidentally deleted the timeout while cleaning up my code. The code bellow solves everything.

```js
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    stdout = stdout + data.toString();

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send([stdout], {
            code: true,
            split: true
        });
    }, 3000)
});
```